# Identifying if /tmp is on a separate partition

Tags: linux, partitioning

I'm still learning and have seen one of the best practice for security is to partition `/tmp` separately from the file system. How do I check whether `/tmp` is in other partition?

If I were to do cd /, is it viewing the whole partition or is that another directory for a separate partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `mount` command, with no arguments. That will list all your mountpoints. If you see that the `/tmp` directory is listed there, it's different partition. Otherwise, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

visualy using

```
 df | grep /tmp
```

in a script

```
  if df | grep -q ' /tmp$' 
  then
       # code for /tmp onwn partition
  else
       # code for /tmp in /
  fi
```

please note that `df` may hang (specially if your are using NFS or SAMBA/CIFS ), you might whish to relay on `mount` instead (`grep` command will be a bit different).

Answer (score 0):

In a more general sense, `df` can be used to discern whether two directories are on different filesystems.  Do that by giving the directory name as an argument to `df`. For example, on the system I am logged into, `df` is easier to work in this sense with than `mount`:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/foo
$ df .
Filesystem                                             1K-blocks         Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8a1efcd1-0d32-4674-aa7a-c24c2cd924fd  19751804 12269912   6478528  66% /
$ df /tmp
Filesystem                                             1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8a1efcd1-0d32-4674-aa7a-c24c2cd924fd  19751804 12269912   6478528  66% /
$ df /
Filesystem                                             1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8a1efcd1-0d32-4674-aa7a-c24c2cd924fd  19751804 12269912   6478528  66% /
$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=125055,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=101324k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/8a1efcd1-0d32-4674-aa7a-c24c2cd924fd on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=382860k)
```

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/df.html) does not specify an output format for `df`.  I seem to recall that some (not Linux) may show the given argument to `df` rather than the mountpoint in the output.  POSIX does not specify `mount` at all (hence the lack of specification for the output of `df`).